# Using lombok annotations with DynamoDB annotations [aws-dynamodb-encryption]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am using AWS encryption client.The below code throwing error as

Error : **@DoNotTouch not applicable on field**

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Getter
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "jktest")
public class DataPoJo {


    private String title;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "dummyname")
    private String dummyname;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "example")
    private String example;


    @DoNotEncrypt
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @DoNotTouch
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="someProp")
    private String someProp;

}
```

However If i give **@DoNotTouch** config as below [with getters and setters]

```
private String someProp;
@DoNotTouch
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="someProp")
public String getSomeProp() {
    return someProp;
}

public void setSomeProp(String someProp) {
    this.someProp = someProp;
}
```

This is working fine.I guess getters and setters generated by lombok is not recognized by AmazonEncryptionclient

I am following this aws doc :  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/client-side-encryption-for-amazon-dynamodb/

Did any one faced this issue ? how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to use [onX](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX) feature of lombok.below code fixed the problem

```
@Getter(onMethod = @_(@DoNotTouch))
 @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="someProp")
 private String someProp;
```

Comment: Be careful with annotations that generate annotations. They break compile time injection frameworks like Dagger.   (@_...).